# What elements of a login form do I need to perform this web scraping task?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I'm trying to log in and scrape a grading website. I've set up the following code to access the website and enter a pay load of:
- username/email
- password
- csrf_token
Is there additional information that I need to include in my payload in order to log in?

I'm using python 2.7. I've added code to print out the last page the script opens and it prints out the login page making me think that it never successfully logged in.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

payload = {
    "username": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "csrf_token": "ImE2N2E1YzkzZGU2ZjY3NjQ0YTc4YmZiYWJjNWRiN2Y3MjlhYWZmYjQi.XBvDVg.ALSRF6Ui7Y2L7ST0kQG-CC4HTzQ"
}

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://www.zipgrade.com/login"
user_url = 'https://www.zipgrade.com/user'

result = session_requests.get(login_url)

# make HTML parse tree from page
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = 
list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='csrf_token']")))[0]

# send payload through
result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data = payload,
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

result = session_requests.get(
    user_url,
    headers = dict(referer = user_url)
)

tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
bucket_names = tree.xpath("//div[@class='row']")
print(result.ok)

print(bucket_names[0].text_content().strip())
```

I would like it to take me to the 'https://www.zipgrade.com/user' page but it looks like its staying on the 'https://www.zipgrade.com/login' page.

Comment: Have you checked the headers sent and Chrome Developer Tools network tab when you perform a manual login attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. it seems there's a session token passed in the cookie header; I just tried to mimic a login and my request looked like this:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www,zipgrade,com")

payload = "username=some%40email.com&password=some%40password&csrf_token=IjhmNWU1Y2EzYWExMjcwM2FiZmY5MjEzOGUwNDQ2N2UxZWQ4ODY0OTMi.XBwSeg.RU2oZBM15U7-ECl1Ldfv7LYlcnQ%5E&origURL="

headers = {
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'Cache-Control': "max-age=0",
    'Origin': "https://www.zipgrade.com",
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
    'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    'Referer': "https://www.zipgrade.com/login/",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
    'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    'Cookie': "session=eyJfcGVybWFuZW50Ijp0cnVlLCJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjp7IiBiIjoiT0dZMVpUVmpZVE5oWVRFeU56QXpZV0ptWmpreU1UTTRaVEEwTkRZM1pURmxaRGc0TmpRNU13PT0ifX0.XBwSeg.EPMMH0CcBMif4qUoxGPKFvcnzRw",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "865a89b0-c5cc-49b1-9e24-df413be64fc0"
    }

conn.request("POST", "login,", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Notice that your payload is correct; you are passing the parameters right; however there is a session passed in the header; you need to obtain the session token and pass it with your header;

I'd make two requests, one is a plain request to the login page https://www.zipgrade.com/login/ which will return back a cookie containing the session parameter you need; parse the cookie and extract the session; when done resume to your scraping function and make sure you update the header variable with that session;

When you bang the URL for the session, you can grab the csrf token at the same time from the hidden input field eg:

This way your first call prepares you for the scraping call; by gathering the dynamic tokens from both cookie and hidden input field.

Keep in mind sessions on different sites have different expiration times; some session tokens can be used in multiple page scraping while others need to obtain a new session each jump. Just a tip; but I think this will lead you in the right direction.